# Hide vertical lines in the gridview for hidden columns

Tags: asp.net, css, .net, vb.net, gridview

Visual Studio: 2010
Framework: 4.0
Code behind: VB.Net

I am building web site in asp.net. I used grid view for displaying data. I want vertical lines on visible columns only. For this purpose I used gridline property of gridview. But it applied on all the columns in the gridview. In grid view there are some invisible (hide) columns. So I don’t want to apply on those columns which are hidden. I tried to decrease the column width but its not working.
So how hide grid lines for hidden columns. Attached screen shot of my grid view.

Decreasing width of column I used below code:

```
gridview1.Columns (8).ItemStyle.Width = 0
```

I used below property for setting the vertical line on the grid view.

```
gridview1.GridLines="Vertical"
```

Below is screen shot of my grid view:

[image: Hide Vertical GridView lines for hidden columns]

Comment: does not display:none on th / td of hidden columns works ? width keeps it there and keep padding too

Comment: Can you change the underlying data to not have the columns?  It might be easier than messing with the GUI.

Comment: As @SteveWellens said, please consider using [DataKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of setting the hidden visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually toggle the Visibility of `ColumnCollection` at the `DataBound` Event like this.

```
Protected Sub gridview1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles gridview1.DataBound
    gridview1.Columns(7).Visible = False
    gridview1.Columns(8).Visible = False
    gridview1.Columns(9).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide column in rowdatabound event. Assuming the columns to be hidden have index 7,8,9

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;  
    e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false; 
    e.Row.Cells[9].Visible = false; 
}
```

In aspx attach rowdatabound event to above function by assigning onrowdatabound property to gridview

```
<asp:Gridview id="gridview1" runat="server" onrowdatabound="gridview1_RowDataBound">
.
.
.
</asp:GridView>
```